# Find customers with similar tastes while excluding certain customers

Tags: mysql

I have a table documenting purchases from customers, with one row per purchase:

```
CustomerID  |  ProductID 
1           |  1000 
1           |  2000 
1           |  3000 
2           |  1000 
3           |  1000 
3           |  3000 
...         |  ...
```

I am using the following code to find the ten customers with the greatest number of overlapping products with customer #1 (first result is the one with the most overlap etc):

```
SELECT othercustomers.CustomerID, COUNT(DISTINCT othercustomers.ProductID)
FROM `purchases` AS thiscustomer
JOIN `purchases` AS othercustomers ON
    thiscustomer.CustomerID != othercustomers.CustomerID
    AND thiscustomer.ProductID = othercustomers.ProductID
WHERE thiscustomer.CustomerID = '1'
GROUP BY othercustomers.CustomerID
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT othercustomers.ProductID) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The code yields the expected output (Customer ID + total number of overlapping products with customer #1).

I would now like the query to exclude customers with overlapping purchases who have purchased more than 1000 different products, because these are bulk buyers who purchase the entire stock and whose purchase history therefore has no meaning when searching for customers with a similar taste.

In other words, if customer #500 had bought >1000 different products, I want him/her excluded from the results when searching for customers with a similar taste to that of customer #1 - even if customer #500 has bought all three products that customer #1 had bought and would ordinarily rank first in similarity/overlap.

I suppose some `HAVING` is in order, but I cannot seem to figure out what the appropriate condition is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that `HAVING` won't do what you want, since it will only give you the total count of *overlaping* products, while you want the total count of products for the other customer.

You could filter with a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT othercustomers.CustomerID, COUNT(DISTINCT othercustomers.ProductID)
FROM `purchases` AS thiscustomer
JOIN `purchases` AS othercustomers ON
    thiscustomer.CustomerID != othercustomers.CustomerID
    AND thiscustomer.ProductID = othercustomers.ProductID
WHERE 
    thiscustomer.CustomerID = '1'
    AND (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID) 
        FROM `purchases` AS p
        WHERE p.CustomerID = othercustomers.CustomerID
    ) < 1000
GROUP BY othercustomers.CustomerID
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT othercustomers.ProductID) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

For performance, you want an index on `purchases(CustomerID, ProductID)`.

Comment: Thanks, but this query takes forever to execute (it's been running for a few minutes now and is not done yet...). EDIT: To clarify, the previous query used to take 1-3 seconds to execute.

Comment: @GummySQL: to get this additional information, you need another scan on `purchaes`. I added an index recommendation to my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the index does not seem to help.

Comment: Is there a way I can add a third column to the results, containing the number of purchases per user, using (another) `JOIN` and in this way circumvent the performance issues of a subquery?